# Prove that the circle $S^1$ is not the boundary of any compact manifold with boundary in $\mathbb R^2-{(0,0)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Suppose it were, then define a 1-form $w:=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(-y\,\mathrm dx+x\,\mathrm dy)$. Firstly , I try to evaluate $\int_{S^1}w$ by two ways . Firstly, let $F\colon[0,2 \pi]\to S^1$ defined by $F(\theta)=(\sin\theta, \cos\theta)$, then $\int_{S^1}w=\int_{[0,2\pi]} F^{\ast}w=\int_{[0,2\pi]}(-\cos^2\theta \,\mathrm d\theta+\sin^2\theta \,\mathrm d\theta)=-2\pi$.

Then I want to evaluate $\int_{S^1}w$ by using Stoke's theorem (This uses the assupmtion that $S^1$ is the boundary of some compact manifold with boundary in $\mathbb R^2-{(0,0)}$).

If the result of this integral is different from $-2\pi$, then I can conclude the assumption is false, thus proving the result. However, I don't know how to evaluate by using Stoke, I am stuck with how to change the 1-form into 0-form and evaluate it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Stokes' theorem works the other way around: Integrate the $2$-form $d\omega$ (which is $\equiv0$) over the two-dimensional domain in $\dot{\mathbb R}^2$ supposedly bounded by $S^1$.

Comment: If $S^1=\partial M$, then Stokes's theorem says $\int_{S^1} w=\int_M dw$, but $dw=0$ on $\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: This point is clear from the question already, but I want to emphasize that when you say "the circle $S^1$", you mean the *unit* circle in $\mathbb R^2$. There are plenty of other embedded circles in $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ that do bound disks (e.g. take the boundary of the disk of radius 2 centred at $(0, 500)$). In this problem, there is no ambiguity, but it is often useful to keep track of what you mean exactly. (In particular, after you have figured this out, a good exercise is to see the difference between my circle and your circle.)

Comment: @Landscape,Thanks for your help. But how did you get dw=0? I know this is stupid , but I am not familiar with these caculation techniques.

Comment: @tagb78: For a $1$-form $w=pdx+qdy$, by definition, $dw=(\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial p}{\partial y})dx\wedge dy$.

Comment: @Landscape Consider posting your comments as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S^1$ is the only boundary component, then such a compact manifold would have to be both open and (relatively) closed in $\mathbb R^2-{(0,0)}$, and so it would have to be either the interior or the exterior of the circle, neither of which is a compact manifold.  Here one doesn't need to use the Jordan curve theorem because your circle is standard.